# In Jetpack compose, what is difference using in BasicTextField for textStyle property LocalTextStyle or MaterialTheme?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've this question, maybe trivial, setting up BasicTextField textStyle property,for set text color for example, I can use one of this 3:

```
textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.White)

textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(color = Color.White)

textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.body1.copy(color = Color.White)
```

someone could explain me the difference pros/cons? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

`textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.White)`

This one is just using hardcoded style for composable. Nothing fancy

`textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(color = Color.White)`

This one is copying style that is provided by a `CompositionLocal` via composable higher up in the hierarchy. The advantage is that you do not hardcode anything about the style in your composable. Instead - higher composable is providing the style dynamically for you. Disadvange - the `LocalTextStyle` might not be set. Although `MaterialTheme` containers (like `Surface`, `Button` or `Scaffold`) sets that  one for you.

As an example usage - when you create a `MaterialTheme` `Button` you can do a simple `Text(text = "whatever")` and so not set the style. The text style will be provided automatically by the `Button` itself, so all of the buttons have the same text styles. This is using `LocalTextStyle` under the hood

`textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.body1.copy(color = Color.White)`

This is using a style from a theme (`MaterialTheme` in this example). The advantage is that you stating you want to use particular style of text. Details about the style are provided by a theme. Cannot think of disadvantages here really, other than binding your composable to the given theme

Comment: can you please provide more details on LocalTextStyle? Maybe make some examples. I set my fonts, but when I do Text(text = "whatever") font is not changing.